# How to calculate a integration of a self-definite function in R?

Tags: r, integrate

I intend to calculate the variance of a method however the expression is quite a mess.

In order to calculate this, I used the most inefficient way. I defined a function "a" which is

```
a<-function(x){
  (x/2*exp(-x^2/4)/(1/(sqrt(2*pi)*sqrt(2))*exp(-(x-4)^2/(2*2)))-0.01831564)^2*(1/(sqrt(2*pi)*sqrt(2))*exp(-(x-4)^2/(2*2)))
}
```

and use the command

```
 integrate(a,lower=0,upper=Inf)
```

however it cannot show the result.what's wrong with my usage and is there any easy way to do this?Thanks!

the error message is

```
integrate(a, lower = 0, upper = Inf) : non-finite function value
```

Comment: the error message is----integrate(a, lower = 0, upper = Inf) : non-finite function value

Comment: `a` appears to underflow: `curve(a,from=0,to=100,log="y")`

Comment: So actually it cannot count by R?thx